# Is this a sufficient proof that there exist unique numbers n and  such that x = n + , where n is an integer and $\epsilon$ ∈ [0, 1)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

I am trying to create a proof for the aforementioned theorem; it seems rather obvious that it is a true statement, but I am still new to creating and rigorizing proofs, so I want to make sure I am at least on the right track.

Here is the proof that I came up with:

1. any real number either is an integer or falls between two integers, $n$ and $n + 1$
2. $x$ is a real number, therefore $n \le x \lt n + 1$
3. $0 \le \epsilon \lt 1$
4. add $n$ to all sides: $n \le n + \epsilon \lt n + 1$
5. because $n + \epsilon$ can be any value between $n$ and $n + 1$, and $x$ falls between $n$ and $n + 1$, it follows that any $x$ must be able to be represented as $n + \epsilon$

Although this seems (at least almost) sufficient to prove existence, I am really unsure about how to prove uniqueness in this case. I am also not sure whether it is rigorous enough. I would love your guys' input/suggestions on how to improve my proof. :)

Comment: Looks fine. For the uniqueness you can find the exact $\epsilon$ that do the work.
For instances, if $n \leq x \leq n+1$ then $0 \leq x-n \leq 1$ and you can take $\epsilon = x-n$. As $x$ and $n$ are unique, then follow that $\epsilon$ is unique.

Comment: @BrianBritosSimmari thank you very much for your reply. That is a clever way to deduce that $\epsilon$ is unique, I did not think of that.

Comment: $\varepsilon = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I am unfamiliar with the notation ⌊⌋.
Could you explain what the ⌊⌋ signify? It is difficult to look them up as Google doesn't recognize them as characters.

Comment: It;s called the "floor function". In your case $\lfloor x \rfloor = n$ is just the $n$ you found

Comment: @student91 Thanks! And is that supposed to help prove uniqueness? I don't really understand how the statement $\epsilon = x - ⌊x⌋$ helps to prove the uniqueness of $n$ and $\epsilon$